# Google contacts API returns low resolution photos

Tags: java, contacts, gdata, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using Google's Data APIs Java library to access contacts and when using the getContactPhotoLink() method I can only get low resolution (96x96) photos. Is there anyway I can get bigger resolution photos?

On my Android phone the photos showing up are definitely not 96x96 pixels...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on the version of Android.

If you have anything under ICS 4.0 then the maximum image size is 96x96.
It may look bigger on your phone, but thats because the image is being scaled to fit the screen. So if you want a bigger image just scale it to fit.

ICS 4.0 supports images of up to 256x256

Jelly Bean 4.1 and above currently support up to 720x720