# GdataContact fetched user photo is at low resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts, google-profiles-api

I am using the Google data contact API to fetch a user`s photo. However, it appears the photo returned are about low resolution. is that possible to get a higher resolution photo? Below are the code I am using to fetch the photo:

```
**NSURL *imageURL = [[contact photoLink] URL];
GDataServiceGoogleContact *service = [self contactService];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [service requestForURL:imageURL
                                                 ETag:nil
                                           httpMethod:nil];

[request setValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];

NSLog(@"URLRequest %@",request);

fetcher.retryEnabled = YES;
fetcher.maxRetryInterval = 0.3;
[fetcher setAuthorizer:[service authorizer]];
[fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
              didFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];**
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392675/google-contacts-api-returns-low-resolution-photos?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079093/google-contacts-api-gdata-syncs-low-resolution-photos. It seems using contacts API the picture size can be 96x96

Comment: I have seen those links, but doesn't seems providing a way of having a higher resolution.